# Box.com authorization for webhooks

Tags: authorization, webhooks, box

In trying to setup a webhook for our box.com app, I noticed that there isn't an option to be passed an authorization_code.  Without that, the code on our end will be unable to grab the updated content of the file from box.com.

The simplified workflow is:

- User chooses "More actions" for a file in their box.com account,
  and then clicks "Send to XYZ".
- This sends pops up a window which
  sends the user to our webapp, passing us the file id and an
  authorization code.
- Our webapp uses the authorization code to
  download the file and store it on our end, tagging the resource with
  the box.com file id for future refence.
- User chooses to "Upload
  New Version" in box.com and uploads a new file.
- Webhook triggers
  and issues a GET to our webapp passing in the file id.
- Our webapp
  looks up the downloaded file by id and then attempts to download the
  new version.  We need an authorization code to do this.  (The
  original authorization code has long since expired.)

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Am I just missing something, or is this not possible currently with box.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, our solution was to use the OAuth2 refresh tokens obtained during the initial use of the incoming auth_code.  This refresh token (according to the box.com docs) should last about 60 days or so.  So we created a background job to look for expiring refresh tokens and update them.  Not an ideal solution at all (and quite awkward in the code), but it seems to be the best option available.